# Connection between $S$ and $A$ when $S^{-1} A S$ is a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

In diagonalizing a matrix $A$, we use a matrix $S$, which consists of eigenvectors of $A$.  To compute $S$, we simply take each eigenvector of $A$ and write it as a linear combination of the *standard* basis.  So if $(1,4,3)$ were an eigenvector of $A$, then writing it in the standard basis gives $1e_1 + 4e_2 + 3e_3$.  Taking the transpose of the coefficients gives the first column in $S$.

My question is: the matrix $S$ is *not* a matrix representation of the operator corresponding to matrix $A$.  It is simply one of the factors that multiplies with $A$ and $S^{-1}$, to give the diagonal matrix, which *is* a matrix representation of the operator corresponding to matrix $A$, but in the diagonalizing basis.  So, what is $S$ *by itself*?  Just something that we call a "transition matrix", or a "change of coordinate matrix"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general name for it is a change of basis matrix. Since $A$ is diagonalizable, its eigenvectors span its domain, so every vector in its domain can be written as a linear combination of eigenvectors. Thus, the action of $A$ can be described by its action on each of the eigenvectors (which is multiplication by the eigenvalues). So if we choose to represent the operator corresponding to $A$ in the basis of its eigenvectors, $A$ is diagonal. The matrix $S$ transforms the diagonal matrix into the standard basis.

Comment: Hi, @AlexS, I am guessing your last sentence should read "transforms the diagonalizing basis into the standard basis."  Yea...I'm just wondering whether S has any computational (or theoretical) significance by itself.  Like, would it even mean anything if we took vectors in the domain of A ...and multiplied it with S?  What would S(x) even mean?  It wouldn't be the action of A.  Seems like nonsense to me, but I just wanted to ask anyway.  Thanks,

Comment: Good question. The representation of a vector as a lots of numbers is also relative to the basis. The numbers, as you noted, represent the coefficients of each of the basis vectors to be added together to get the vector. Multiplying $S$ by a vector given in the standard basis would would give a new vector which is a linear combination of the eigenvectors with coefficients the same as the entries in the original vector.